# How to change price format or locale options in Magento 1.5?

Tags: magento, localization, locale, precision, number-formatting

**I'm going to write a common problem in magento and a solution, which best fit for me.**

I've been searchin the net and reflecting magento code for hours to find solution to the above problem. I wanted Hungarian price format to be `1 000 Ft` instead of `1 000,00 Ft`

I have replaced the value `'precision'` to 0 everywhere, but did not succeed.
Here is a list where I probed:

- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php

  `function formatPrice(){ $option = array('precison' => 2 ); ... }`
- app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php

  `function format() {
      $this->formatPrecision($price, 0, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
  }`

After reflecting the code I realized that this all change does not matter at all because number format information is based on *locale* information which is provided by the *Zend core API*.

**So here is the solution I found and hopefully price formatting will be standard for the entire application this way.**

You find your *YY.xml* file in *lib/Zend/Locale/Data/*, where *YY* is your countries locale code. Mine is *hu.xml*

You find the part:

```
<currencyFormats>
    <currencyFormatLength>
        <currencyFormat>
            <pattern>#,##0 ¤</pattern>
        </currencyFormat>
    </currencyFormatLength>
    <unitPattern count="other">{0} {1}</unitPattern>
</currencyFormats>
```

About the format string you can find a not-at-all useful information at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.parsing.html

Comment: format string link is dead

Answer (score -2):

Copy "app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php" to "app/code/local/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php" and replace the format function.

```
public function format($price, $options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
    {
        return str_replace(',00', '', $this->formatPrecision($price, 2, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets));        
    }
```

Comment: you dont need to use str_replace, just modify second parametr from 2 to 0